# How do we hide sibling div h2 using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>Referral Schedules</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
   <script="javascript">
   </script>
   <iframe width="100%" height="100" frameborder="0" src="www.google.com">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a page in which i have control over the portion of HTML, ie the div where we have the iframe. I need some way to hide the h2 tag.

Answer (score 2):

`$('div > div > h2').hide();`

Prodably the best way to do it.

But why, really. why? use a class.

If it were me id'e do something special like this

```
<div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="heading-sibling">Referral Schedules</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
   <script="javascript">
      $(function(){
        $('.heading-sibling').hide();
      });
   </script>
   <iframe width="100%" height="100" frameborder="0" src="www.google.com"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately i dont have control over the rest of the code. The rest of the code is generated from salesforce and i just have the div on which javascript tags are there to play around with

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the HTML part I would add an identifier for the iframe-container to find it more quickly:

```
<div id="iframe_container">
   <script="javascript">
   </script>
   <iframe width="100%" height="100" frameborder="0" src="www.google.com">
</div>
```

Then you could use the [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method from jquery like this:

```
$('#iframe_container').siblings().find('h2').hide();
```

Here's the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bgc5f/